# Java synchronization primitive

Tags: java, concurrency

I want the following semaphore-like synchronization primitive in my code:

```
class Event {
    private boolean fired = false;

    public synchronized void fire() {
        this.fired = true;
        this.notify();
    }

    public synchronized void waitFor() throws InterruptedException {
        while (!this.fired)
            wait();
        this.fired = false;
    }
}
```

Is there a primitive in Java standard library (or other popular libraries) that can be used with the same semantics?

EDIT: It seems that `CountDownLatch` is the best possible candidate, so I'm going to accept one of the answers. Although I don't like it in this case because it doesn't provide clear semantics and lacks readability.

Comment: Like the class [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `CountDownLatch`. Initialize with 1 `cdl = new CountDownLatch(1)`, waiting thread will call blocking method `cdl.await()` while the notifying thread will call `cdl.countDown()`.

You will have to create new `CountDownLatch` object as it doesn't have reset method. It's worth to remember about [memory consistency errors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html), but in your case all methods accessing this variable are synchronised so it won't be a problem.

Alternatively, you can use `CyclicBarier` and then all threads will be calling `cb.await()`. Initialise it with the number of threads `cb = new CyclicBarrier(2)` and then method `await` will block until 2 threads are waiting and will let only these 2 threads go forward.

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.concurrent` provides high level concurrency.

`CountDownLatch` will resolve your query.

Please go through [docuementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)